# Finding the solution sequence for a sequence of linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

I'd like to find a formulation of the solution $x_{i_1 i_2...i_n}$ of a linear system $S_n$ of a sequence of linear systems $(S_1, S_2, S_3, ...)$, defined as follows:

---

Let $i, j, ... \in I:=\{1,2\}$.

### $S_1:$

The single equation $$y_1 = \sum_i x_{i},$$
where $x_{2}$ is unknown. The solution is

$x_2 = -x_1 + y_1$.

---

### $S_2:$

$$y_1 = \sum_{ij} x_{ij},$$ 
$$y_{21} = \sum_{j} x_{1j}, y_{22} = \sum_{i} x_{i1},$$ 
These are
3 equations ($2^2 - 1$) with 3 unknown variables $\{x_{ij}|i+j>2\}$.

The solution is

$x_{12} = -x_{11} + y_{21}$

$x_{21} = -x_{11} + y_{22}$

$x_{22} = +x_{11} - y_{21} - y_{22} + y_1 $

---

### $S_3:$

$$y_1 = \sum_{ijk} x_{ijk},$$ 
$$y_{21} = \sum_{jk} x_{1jk}, y_{22} = \sum_{ik} x_{i1k}, y_{23} = \sum_{ij} x_{ij1}$$ 
$$y_{312} = \sum_{k} x_{11k}, y_{313} = \sum_{j} x_{1j1}, y_{323} = \sum_{i} x_{i11}$$ 
$2^3 - 1 = 7$ equations with 7 unknown variables $\{x_{ijk}|i+j+k>3\}$.

The solution is

$x_{112} = -x_{111} + y_{312}$,

$x_{121} = -x_{111} + y_{313}$,

$x_{122} = +x_{111} - y_{312} - y_{313} + y_{21}$,

$x_{211} = -x_{111} + y_{323}$,

$x_{212} = +x_{111} - y_{312} - y_{323} + y_{22}$,

$x_{221} = +x_{111} - y_{313} - y_{323} + y_{23}$,

$x_{222} = -x_{111} + y_{312} + y_{313} + y_{323} - y_{21} - y_{22} - y_{23} + y_1$

---

### $\vdots$

---

### $S_n:$

$$y_1 = \sum_{i_1,..., i_n} x_{i_1 \cdots i_n},$$

$$\forall k \in \{1, ..., n\}: y_{2 k} = \sum_{\{i_1,..., i_n|i_{k}=1\}} x_{i_1 \cdots i_n},$$

$$\forall k_1, k_2 \in \{1, ..., n\} \wedge k_1 < k_2: y_{3 k_1 k_2} = \sum_{\{i_1,..., i_n|i_{k_1}=i_{k_2}=1\}} x_{i_1 \cdots i_n},$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\forall k_1, ..., k_{n-1} \in \{1, ..., n\} \wedge k_i < k_j: 
y_{3 k_1 ... k_{n-1}} = \sum_{\{i_1,..., i_n|i_{k_1}=...=i_{k_{n-1}}=1\}} x_{i_1 \cdots i_n},$$

$2^n - 1$ equations with $2^n - 1$ unknown variables $\{x_{i_1\cdots i_n}|\sum i_k>n\}$.

What's the solution here? Is there maybe some nice algebraic (matrix, tensor) formulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given variables $x_R$ and constants $y_T$ for all subsets $R,T\subseteq[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. In your notation $x_R$ corresponds to $x_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}$ with $i_k=1$ for $k\in R$ and $i_k=2$ for $k\in[n]\setminus R$. The constants $y_T$ for $T=\{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_\ell\}$ correspond to your $y_{\ell+1,k_1,k_2,\dots,k_\ell}$. Your equations may now be expressed as
$$
\sum_{R\supseteq T} x_R = y_T \tag{1}
$$
for each $T\subseteq[n]$. In particular $x_{[n]} = y_{[n]}$ is your $x_{11\dots 1}$.

In your examples you can already see that the $y_T$ will always just appear with coefficients $1$ and $-1$ in the solution, depending on the size of $T$. Indeed, we have
$$ x_R = \sum_{S\supseteq R} (-1)^{|S\setminus R|} y_S,$$
which can easily be verified to be a solution to (1) using the fact that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} (-1)^k = (1 + (-1))^m =0.$$